# How do I save using GNU datamash Transpose column and row?

Tags: bash, save, gnuplot, gnu

I have 800MiB .dat file. I need to transpose data in that file from columns to rows so that I can use gnuplot with it. I found out `datamash` can do it in terminal but I have no idea how to save the transposed data to a .txt or .dat file. When i use:

```
$datamash transpose < input.dat
```

I get the outprint in the terminal but it doesn't change the actual file. How do I save the transposed data? If you have other way of doing this please tell me I'm a complete newbie and self-learner.

Thanks!

P.S. I use bash terminal but on windows 10 (supports everything linux does) >> if it mattered in any way :)

Comment: `datamash transpose < input.dat > output.dat`?

Comment: Works great thanks!